# How to change destination of paymentintent in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I run a marketplace, where customers pay and reserve for a specialised service.
We use Stripe with Stripe Connect to handle payments.

In my business, **we don't know who is going to do the job when the customer pay** and it can even change several times. I tried to update the paymentIntent with no success, and the API documentation is not clear about the possibility.

Is it possible to change the destination of an existing paymentIntent ? And more precisely how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options :

You could use Separate Charge and Transfers (SCT) where you charge the customer first and then transfer the funds to the service provider later. [0]

You could also use auth and capture [1] where you "reserve" the funds first with no destination (i.e. a charge on your platform). Once you know who the service provider is, you can cancel the charge, and then immediately create another charge and capture it with the correct destination.

[0]https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers

[1]https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later